# почему не показывает SVG в IE, а Chrome и Firefox показывает?

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<img src="" class="grey-icon float-left icon-clock" />

.icon-clock {
  background-image: url("../images/clock.svg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

это не показывает только IE, а Chrome и Firefox показывает.
есть способ показывает SVG в IE только лишь:

```
<li class="top-link icon-clock"><a href="#/archive.html">Home</a></li>
.top-link {
  color: $black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  background-image: url("../images/home.svg");
  background-size: 14px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: 0 50%;
}
```

Comment: какой ie&??????

Comment: от ie 10, а  до IE 9 не поддерживает SVG